# Keystonejs in production mode in GAE: can't build the admin ui

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, keystonejs

Accessing the admin UI in GAE (standard nodejs) fails because while building the admin ui, Keystonejs seems to be trying to create files in GAE environment (mkdir or create file).

In my case, it's while trying to build the less files and thus create `/srv/node_modules/keystone/admin/public/styles/keystone.min.css` when I try to reach `/keystone/signin`.

I tried unsucessfully `KEYSTONE_PREBUILD_ADMIN` option.

I really don't know how to solve this.

- Is there a way to extract the admin ui react app and build it before deployment?
- Is there an hidden option to prevent this kind of issue?

The only other option that I can think of would be to use keystonejs as a headless server, and build my own admin UI in my React App. But it would be a shame not beeing able to use keystonejs CRUD engine for content :/

Comment: There was a feature request, but it's closed. See if you find something useful in the thread (I'm not a JS user): https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/220

Comment: Maybe try to run it locally, then re-deploy the app with the generated files stuffed in the right places, so that re-building them on GAE is not necessary?

Comment: Thanks @DanCornilescu for your answer.

`node_modules` are fetched on GAE environment, so I can't really rely on deploying an admin ui built on a previous local run.

I hope to find something useful in the thread you linked, but as it's talking about version 0.4.0, and now it's v4.0.0, I guess the fixes mentioned would be overrated by now :/

There are some stuff at the end of the thread though, I'll try that ;)